# AWS API Gateway Swagger Export for Postman misses Body Content of Post Request

Tags: swagger, postman, aws-api-gateway

After deploying AWS API Gateway via CLI (using `put-rest-api` and `create-deployment`) I want to do some testing of my API description in Postman.

After exporting the API via AWS Console (MyAPI - Stages - MyStage - Export - Postman) no body content is imported to Postman.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: what do you mean 'body content'? The mapping templates on the integration request?

Comment: body content = parameter marked as `body` (name, in) with schema definition (what I expected to be content of Post-Request body when imported to Postman)

Answer (score 0):

When you export with postman extensions, the swagger file contains the definition of the model and the fact that its a parameter to POST, but postman does not show it in content. This is how postman import works. There is a feature request for this in gihub https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/1235

```
...
"/": {
  "post": {
    "consumes": [
      "application/json"
    ],
    "produces": [
      "application/json"
    ],
    "parameters": [
      {
        "in": "body",
        "name": "TestModel",
        "required": true,
        "schema": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/TestModel"
        }
      }
    ],
    ...

"definitions": {
 "TestModel": {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "photos": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "page": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "pages": {
          "type": "string"
        }
        ...
      }
    }
  },
  "title": "TestModel"
 }
}
}
```